# Getting a weird ClassCastException from Android Studio and not sure how to fix it

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtSuperTypeCallEntry cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression (org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtSuperTypeCallEntry and org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I'm not even sure where I would even start with this to even start trying to identify the problem.

Google does not seem to come up with anything either.

Comment: Which distribution (stable, beta, canary) of Android Studio are using, and are you on the latest version? I'd check Google's issue tracker to see if anyone's already reported a similar issue. If not - your best bet is probably to report it yourself "Help -> Submit Feedback".

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm using stable... I have the following from help:

Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4100M
Cores: 8

Comment: I suggest filing a bug on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it actually turns out I broke it... After a lot of tinkering (and I mean a lot), it turns out that I was incorrectly initialising a view model I had which turned into this erroneous error.

After fixing what I broke, it now works as expected.